# compare two date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have two date in which one is `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` format and another in `dd-mm-yyyy (D1)` format
fristly i split  the `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm` format date to get `dd-mm-yyyy (D2)` format only
then i compare the date D2 and D1 like

```
var D1 = new Date(); 
var D2 = new Date(); 
// D1 = 03-05-2014  this date take as an example
// D2 = 28-04-2014 00:00  this date take as an example
// D1 and D2 are taken by input fields.
    split the D2 date

dat = D2.split(' ');
D2 = dat[0];
//finally D2 is 28-04-2014
if(D2<=D1)
{
  echo "ok";
}
else{
  echo "something is wrong";
}
```

I am always getting the else part, is this because i split the date from `28-04-2014 00:00` to `28-04-2014` ?

Comment: what type of result you need as the output ?

Comment: true part of if condition

Comment: actually it compare only day i don't know why, it don't compare whole date

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23402449/1470607

Comment: not getting an answere..

Comment: if D2 is an date, how come you do a split over it?

Answer (score 7):

```
dateFirst = D1.split('-');
dateSecond = D2.split('-');
var value = new Date(dateFirst[2], dateFirst[1], dateFirst[0]); //Year, Month, Date
var current = new Date(dateSecond[2], dateSecond[1], dateSecond[0]);
```

than use the if condition

```
if(D2<=D1)
{
console.log('ok');
}
else
{
console.log('something is wrong');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is you need actually

```
var D1 = "03-05-2014";
var D2 = "28-04-2014 00:00";

if ((new Date(D1).getTime()) >= (new Date(D2).getTime())) {
    alert('correct');
} else {
    alert('wrong');
}
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w8CL4/)

Comment: by this i have no need to split date to get 28-04-2014 from 28-04-2014 00:00 ?

Comment: yes.parse any date string to object and compare times

Comment: You don't need to _getTime_ because of how _valueOf_ a _Date_ is defined

Answer (score 3):

That is a string comparison you are doing, not a date comparison

In terms of strings... 2 is greater than 0... That's why you always hit the "something is wrong" statement

**EDIT:** This is an explanation of what went wrong
    // Creates a date variable
    var D1 = new Date();

```
// Creates another date variable
var D2 = new Date();

// Converts this date variable into a string
D1 = 03-05-2014 

// This is too is converted into a string
D2 = 28-04-2014 00:00

    dat = D2.split(' ');
D2 = dat[0];

//finally D2 is 28-04-2014  <-- true, but it is a string
if(D2<=D1){    //   <-- At this point you are doing a string comparison

        echo "ok";

} else {

    echo "something is wrong";

}
```

**EDIT:** This is a possible solution. . .

Instead of that, do this

```
var D1 = new Date();
var D2 = new Date();

if(D2.getTime() <= D1.getTime()){
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "something is wrong";
}
```

**EDIT:** If you are getting it from an input field, then do this

```
// Make sure you dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DD.
    // In other words, 28-04-2014 00:00 becomes 2014-04-28 00:00
// Javascript Date only accepts the ISO format by default
var D1 = new Date( $('#input1#').val() );
var D2 = new Date( $('#input2#').val() );

    if(D2.getTime() <= D1.getTime()){
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "something is wrong";
}
```

Comment: this has to be a comment

Comment: i take variable date type

Comment: Tarzan, you did make it a date at the beggining....but later you changed it into a string using `D1 = 03-05-2014`. Look at my answer for an explanation and solution.

Comment: no no i am taking date from input field, here i mention only to take as an example

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var msg = new Date("03-05-2014").getTime() >= new Date("28-04-2014 00:00").getTime() ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong';
alert(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();
var end = new Date(//some other date hear);
if(now>end)
{
     console.log('now=',now);
}
else
{
    console.log('end=',end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can date compare as most simple and understandable way like.

```
<input type="date" id="getdate1" />   //with time include
<input type="date" id="getdate2" /> // without time include
```

so firstly write a common method to parse date method.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function parseDate(input) {   
                  var parts = input.split(' ');
              var datecomp=parts[0];  // will get 
              var timecomp=parts[1];  // will get time
                  var dparts=datecomp.split('-');
             if(timecomp!=undefined && timecomp!=null){ //if there is like
                             var tparts=timecomp.split(':');
     return new Date(dparts[2], dparts[1]-1, dparts[0], tparts[0], tparts[1]); 


 }else{  // for when no time is givin
    return new Date(dparts[2], dparts[1]-1, dparts[0]); 
                                              }
                                             return "";
                                              }
            </script>
```

by here you can call above method

```
<script type="text/javascript">

              $(document).ready(function(){
              //parseDate(pass in this method date);
                    Var Date1=parseDate($("#getdate1").val());
                        Var Date2=parseDate($("#getdate2").val());
               //use any oe < or > or = as per ur requirment 
               if(Date1 = Date2){
         return false;  //or your code {}
}
 });
    </script>
```

Just use parseDate method and compare any type of the date.

Answer (score -1):

Convert them into milliseconds, then do comparision

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: This should be a comment. If you want to, you could turn it into a **full** answer by adding more detailed information and/or examples.