# Date comparison operator - logical issue

Tags: javascript, date, date-comparison

I have this simple js function:

```
function checkTime() {  
  var d1 = new Date();
  var d2 = new Date('April 10, 2017 12:11:00');

  if (d1 < d2) {
    $('#modalnew').modal('show');
  } else {
    window.location.replace('https://www.example.php');
  }
}
```

It works fine, but I don't understand the date comparison. This may be a "dumb" question, but I can't find answers on google.
F.E.: - no code, just an example -

```
d1 (now) = April 10, 2017 12:22:00
d2 (date set) = April 10, 2017 12:11:00
```

Why is the `d1` less than `d2` and activates the `window.location`? In a logical order `d1` it is 11 minutes greater than `d2`. On which parameter does it exactly compare?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: d1 < d2 is false that is why the else part is fired so technically di is not less than d2 its executing right isn't it?

Comment: Voting to close because OPs assumption is clearly wrong and does not even need an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `d1` is not less but more than `d2` which is the expected result and hence the `window.location.replace` is executed .

While comparing the date  it evaluates to if `(d1.valueOf()< d2.valueOf())` . `valueOf()` delivers time in `milliseconds`  since beginning of `00:00:00 UTC Thursday 1, January 1970` and then compares it.

Comment: Ahh, okay, so it counts continual up and the current date is always less than a date in the future?

Comment: Yes it will be, since its measured from a particular time

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes it clear! :) I will tag your answer as right, as it is possible in a few mins.

Answer (score 2):

To compare two dates you better use [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method that returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.

The result number for each date `d1` and `d2` will explain better the short and bigger date.

Code:

```
function checkTime() {  
  var d1 = new Date();
  var d2 = new Date('April 10, 2017 12:11:00');

  d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()
    ? $('#modalnew').modal('show')
    : window.location.replace('https://www.example.php');
}
```

Comment: No, wrong. You can compare dates using `<` and `>`. it is the `==` and `===` that cause problem (always return false even if dates are same).

Comment: @SalmanA check that [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time. So, you can compare numeric values with `<` and `>`

Comment: I am saying is that two `Date`s can be compared directly using `<` and `>` (and `<=` and `>=`). These operators will call `.valueOf()` method behind the scenes which, for dates, returns same value as `.getTime()`. OPs code is correct and your answer is redundant.

Answer (score -1):

Compare two dates in JavaScript
Convert your time using `getTime()` and then compare  [More Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript) ,[Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443310/compare-two-date-using-javascript), [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w8CL4/)