# How to change color of specific Date of <input type=Date>?

Tags: jquery, css, html, date, calendar

Is there any way to change styling(i.e Color) of input type date of HTML 5
in html 5 we can show calendar via `<input type=date>`
now lets say 23rd of march is holiday and I want to show this specific date in red color, how can i do that ?

I want to change color of specific date while opening calendar ,so that it is visible to the client like I've achieved this using Jquery plugin in the following Picture [image]

Comment: are you using jquery date picker?

Comment: I am not using any plugin,

Comment: you can use jquery date picker and change date color like this https://codepen.io/SaurabhShine/pen/MQPBKp

Comment: @Overflowrun that Question is totally different mate

Comment: @SaurabhSolanki thanks for response but I already know how to do that via jquery plugin.

Comment: ok so i understand the question wrongly as all the answers below ... what you want is impossible actually, there is no way to style the calendar, you can style only the input

Comment: @TemaniAfif That is also what I got from the answers.

Answer (score -1):

Following is the jQuery way to do this.

```
   $('input[type="date"]').change(function{    
        var date = new Date( this.value );
        var specificDate = "23 March 2018";
        if(date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 0 ||  this.value == specificDate) { //Check for Saturday or Sunday
           $(this).css("color","red"); 
        }
        else {
           $(this).css("color","inherit"); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Pure js solution, no jQuery required. You can save your holidays in an array and check if the input is in the array or not.

Refer 
1. [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
2. [Date comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443310/compare-two-date-using-javascript)

```js
function datechanged(el) {
    var holiday = new Date("2018-10-02");
    var holidays = [new Date("2018-10-02").getTime(), new Date("2018-02-02").getTime(), new Date("2018-02-01").getTime()]

    var inputDate = new Date(el.value);
    el.classList.remove("red");

    if(holidays.includes(inputDate.getTime())){
      el.classList.add("red")
    }
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.red{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type=date onchange="datechanged(this)">
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would make an array that contains your especific dates. With that you can target the change of the input. And change the class depending if it finds it in the array.

Iused `indexOf()` and will change the class when the result is different from **-1**

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
const redDates = ['2018-02-26','2018-03-26'];
$('input').change(function() {

  $(this).removeClass('holiday');
  if(redDates.indexOf($(this).val()) != -1)
    $(this).addClass('holiday');

})
```

```css
.holiday {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date">
```